# errors in AndroidManifest.xml file in flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

`

```
<application
    android:label="BMI Calculator"
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:exported="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

`
here is the code and errors are below

Unresolved package app :6
Unresolved class FlutterApplication 16
Attribute android:icon is not allowed here 17
Unresolved class `MainActivity` :10
Attribute android:configChanges is not allowed here :11
Attribute android:hardwareAccelerated is not allowed here :13
Attribute android:launchMode is not allowed here :14
Attribute android:theme is not allowed here :15
Attribute android:windowSoftInputMode is not allowed here :16

i had tried flutter clean ,flutter run and in flutter doctor no error is found . it is also not runing app in emulator
i want a solution or guide that what to do

Comment: When opening that file in Android Studio it shows the same errors for me, but I think it's sort of normal and you can just ignore it. The app should still run regardless. I think that whatever makes your app not run has nothing to do with this. What do you exactly mean with that it doesn't run? You must have some errors occuring I suppose